# Selenium: store scraped data in a list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium for the first time and I'm having some problem get the data tha way I need. Basically, I'd like to get all the years stored in a dropdown menu, this is pretty much the code:

```
<select name="order" id="filter" tabindex="0" class="dropdown" aria-pressed="false">

        <option data-ref="m3" value="months6" selected="">
            last 6 months
        </option>
    
        <option data-ref="y2022" value="year-2022">
            2022
        </option>
    
        <option data-ref="y2021" value="year-2021">
            2021
        </option>
    
        <option data-ref="y2020" value="year-2020">
            2020
        </option>    

    
</select>
```

This is my code to scrape the information:

```
years = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "filter"))
)
print(years.text)
```

This is what I'm getting using `print(years.text)`

```
'    \n         last 6 months\n    \n              2022\n    \n         2021\n    \n         2020\n    \n         Ordini Archiviati\n    '
```

Is there a way to store the information in a list? And not in a string like this?
Thank you all

Comment: You should use a loop and append these in array. Why not using Beautiful Soup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Select](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) class for `<select>` tags

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

years = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "filter")))
select = Select(years)
options = [option.text for option in select.options]
```